# How to download a build process template in C#?

Tags: c#, vb.net, visual-studio-2013, build-process-template

I'm trying to upgrade the current build definitions to use the newest template - TfvcTemplate.12.xaml. I started off by downloading it from the "Edit build definition" window in VS 2013. But I noticed that the template is in Visual Basic, just like the current one that I'm trying to upgrade.

How is possible to get the template in C# instead of Visual Basic?

Comment: The build template is a lot, but it is not in visual basic. It is a XML file. Actually a workflow definition. Which in some parts uses VB similar syntax. Nothing you can do there.

Comment: It's a XAML file actually. I'm quite familiar with that. Thing is, Since .NET 4, Workflow Foundation supports C# as well as VB.NET in the properties window. My question is how to get the build definition with default properties in C# instead of VB.NET

Comment: You do not. Or - you download it and change it. It does SUPPORT it - but it does not provide a way to magically rewrite existing definitions. WHoever creates the definition can choose what syntax he likes. Guess what the build definition you ahve has choosen. HAve fun rewriting it if you want it in C#.

Comment: Who creates it? It's the default tfs 2013 build definition... Is there really not a single default build definition in C#?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All the build definitions provided out of the box by Microsoft use VB style syntax in the workflow definitions. There are no Microsoft provisioned build workflows using C# syntax.